# executing two methods of the same class and waiting for the result of one to continue

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How can I execute two methods at once using async and wait for 1 finalize method to continue with the other?

```
public class Foo{
    public async Task<string> Method1()
    {
        //run a task
        return result;
    }

    public async void Method2(string result)
    {
        //do some work
        //do some work
        //do some work
        //wait for method1
        //do something with result
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
var result = await foo.Method1();
foo.Method2(result);
```

Comment: Note: [async void is generally considered a really bad idea](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/).

Comment: Your question is actually contradictory.  You say you want to execute two methods _"at  once"_ (concurrency) but then you say you want to wait for the first to finish (serialised).  Also, why bother using `async/await`?

Comment: @MickyD Contradictory? That's a pretty basic way of doing work concurrently, "I'll do this work while you do that work and I'll let you know once I need your results" (in fact, the code in TheodorZoulias's answer is what is suggested in MIcrosoft Docs for mixing concurrency with asynchronicity) TPL isn't required here, that's correct, but what if `Method1` performs asynchronous work?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Perhaps.  I'd argue it's semi-parallelism with an added logical continuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
public async Task<string> Method2()
{
    //do some work
    //do some work
    //do some work
    var result = await foo.Method1();
    //do something with result
    return result;
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
var result = await foo.Method2();
```

---

For (semi)parallel execution:

```
public async Task<string> Method2()
{
    var task1 = foo.Method1();
    //do some work
    //do some work
    //do some work
    var result = await task1;
    //do something with result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Camilo OP's problem statement suggests sequential execution is desired, especially since OP seems to want the result from Method1 to be used in Method2.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, you are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @John That's not at all what I understand from `//wait for method1` but let's let the OP decide

Answer (score 3):

Following your sample where Method1 and Method2 called separately (Method2 doesn't aware of Method1) - you will get desired behaviour by passing a `Task` of Method1 to the Method2.

```
public class Service
{
    public async Task<string> MethodOne()
    {
        // do something
        var result = await CalculateSomeResult();
        return result;
    }

    public async Task MethodTwo(Task<string> task)
    {
        // do some work
        // do some work

        var methodOneResult = await task;
        // do something with the result of methodOne
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var service = new Service();

var methodOneTask = service.methodOne();
await service.MethodTwo(methodOneTask);
```

Comment: This is actually another good approach (with minor problem that code does not compile due to `async void` as @CamiloTerevinto pointed out). This is a bit more flexible than merging call to `Method1` directly into `Method2`  as suggested by accepted answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, it was blind copy from OP's question, I assumed asynchronous methods never has `void` signature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `EventWaitHandle`:

```
public class Sequence {
        EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        public async Task Tsk1() {

            Console.WriteLine("Did some work from tsk1");
            handle.Set();

        }
        public async Task Tsk2() {
            handle.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Doing work after tsk1 finished");
            //do some other stuff
        }
    }
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {

                Sequence seq = new Sequence();
                var t2 =Task.Run(seq.Tsk2);
                var t1 =Task.Run(seq.Tsk1);

                await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
                Console.WriteLine("finished both");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, you need Method2 to use the results returned by Method1 - that being said, you need to call Method2 from inside Method1, not after it:

```
public class Foo{
    public async Task<string> Method1()
    {
        //run a task
        return result;
    }

    public async void Method2(string result)
    {
        //do some work
        //do some work
        //do some work
        var intermediaryResult = await Method1();
        //do something with result
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();

await foo.Method2(result);
```

(Also, you have to await Method2 as well - they both are async)

On a side note, you should [never have async void methods unless you have no choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - so Method2 should be returning Task instead.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Why is Method2 declared `Method2(string result)`? Why did you use `await foo.Method2(result);`  if Method2 is an `async void`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm still not sure what OP is trying to achieve, so I'd prefer to wait for clarifications instead of trying to guess what to correct :)

Comment: The answer by @TheodorZoulias makes a lot of sense to me and it would take an extremely wrongly asked question for the OP to not want what that answer shows

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Foo
{
public async Task<string> Method1()
{
    //run a task
    return result;
}

public async void Method2(string result)
{
    //do some work
    //do some work
    //do some work
    //wait for method1
    //do something with result
}
}
await Task.Run(()=>
{
Foo foo = new Foo();
var result = foo.Method1();
foo.Method2(result);
});
```